# Wasting of vertical space by an itemize within a tabularx

Tags: beamer, tabularx, itemize

When I am using an itemize within a tabular(x) cell, it wastes a lot of vertical space.. How can I get rid of it?

[image: Itemize within tabularx waste of vertical space]

My MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{frame}
        \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
            \hline
            Test
            &
            \begin{itemize}
                \item item 1
                \item item2
            \end{itemize}
            \\\hline
        \end{tabularx}

    \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Is the fact that the sample code you posted employs the `beamer` document class important? Or are you maybe interested in solutions that apply to other document classes? Please advise.

Comment: I need it in the beamer context.. :)

Comment: See if https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/623160/fit-this-table-in-beamer can help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{Boadilla}

\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|l|X|}
        \hline
        Test
        &   \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
            \smallskip
        \begin{itemize}
            \item item 1
            \item item2
        \end{itemize}
            \smallskip
            \end{minipage}
        \\\hline
    \end{tabularx}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]